# Profiling concept implementation with NestJS framework

Tags: profiling, nestjs

Not able to find any document related to implementing the **profiling** concepts with **nestjs** framework, can anyone suggest a way for this.

Thanks,

Comment: Any profiling techniques that work with Node work on the NestJS framework. NestJS is a framework that runs on Node. There's nothing special about it, it's not it's own runtime or anything

Comment: @Jay McDoniel Node JS is a Javascript Code but Nest JS is Typescript code.So, how to implement profiling in typescript code. can you please share some documentation

Comment: Nest servers are written in typescript but ran using JavaScript. It's not a Deno framework, it's a Node framework.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel But with NestJS we can improve profiling. We can do similar to Symfony. We can group data by a request - what SQLs were run during this request, what was the request, how long did it take, what was the controller...

Comment: I don't disagree, @MaciejSikorski, I'm just saying that any profiler that already works for Node should and probably will work for Nest, as NestJS is a Node framework

Answer (score 0):

You can profile a nestjs application by running the usual `nest start` command with the `--debug` flag.

```sh
nest start --debug
```

You can see this flag in the nestjs docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-start). The `debug` flag runs the node application in inspect mode (by appending `--inspect` to the underlying node command). Once that is done, the application can be connected to any node debugging/profiling tool. See the [node debugging guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) for more info and a list of popular tools.